# Where are my container images when running kubernetes with containerd?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, containerd

This output says that I'm running kubernetes with `containerd` as the container runtime:

```
k get nodes -o wide
NAME          STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION        INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
k8s-worker3   Ready    <none>                 12d   v1.24.4+k3s1   10.16.24.123   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS   5.15.0-48-generic   containerd://1.6.6-k3s1
k8s-worker1   Ready    <none>                 12d   v1.24.4+k3s1   10.16.24.121   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS   5.13.0-44-generic   containerd://1.6.6-k3s1
k8s-master    Ready    control-plane,master   12d   v1.24.4+k3s1   10.16.24.120   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS   5.15.0-46-generic   containerd://1.6.6-k3s1
k8s-worker2   Ready    <none>                 12d   v1.24.4+k3s1   10.16.24.122   <none>        Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS   5.13.0-44-generic   containerd://1.6.6-k3s1
```

I'm deploying one of my pods, it gets scheduled on node `k8s-worker3`, and `kubectl describe pods/mypod` says the image was already on the node.

But when I run `ctr` on the node it shows that there NO images:

```
user@k8s-worker3:~$ sudo ctr images list
REF TYPE DIGEST SIZE PLATFORMS LABELS
```

And `docker images` doesn't show the correct version of the image.

Here's the processes running containerd:

```
user@k8s-worker3:~$ ps -ef | grep container
root         985       1  0 15:23 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/containerd
root        1106       1  0 15:23 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
root        1312    1057  0 15:23 ?        00:00:12 containerd -c /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/etc/containerd/config.toml -a /run/k3s/containerd/containerd.sock --state /run/k3s/containerd --root /var/lib/rancher/k3s/agent/containerd
root        1918       1  0 15:23 ?        00:00:03 /var/lib/rancher/k3s/data/577968fa3d58539cc4265245941b7be688833e6bf5ad7869fa2afe02f15f1cd2/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace k8s.io -id 5abd3c3104abf812422757d9534c33475819cbf43b64845dd23f535193fed09e -address /run/k3s/containerd/containerd.sock
root        1970       1  0 15:23 ?        00:00:00 /var/lib/rancher/k3s/data/577968fa3d58539cc4265245941b7be688833e6bf5ad7869fa2afe02f15f1cd2/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace k8s.io -id 8c339c15ab8abb3050810b5fcaed817363fcf3b06800b554711b1fa0e95006e2 -address /run/k3s/containerd/containerd.sock
root        3231       1  0 15:25 ?        00:00:01 /var/lib/rancher/k3s/data/577968fa3d58539cc4265245941b7be688833e6bf5ad7869fa2afe02f15f1cd2/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace k8s.io -id 354aa1df3c2a8492a4842efe3882785553501d77f61d9b5ef0bf3343ace2a518 -address /run/k3s/containerd/containerd.sock
user      4957    3094  0 15:48 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto container
```

So what is happening here?  Where is the image on the node??

Comment: @ jersey bean your issue resolved?if yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it

Comment: No, I never figured it out

Comment: Refer this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/) for List All Container Images Running in a Cluster

Comment: @SaiChandiniRouthu my problem with this approach is that it just shows the name of the images as known by K8s.  But I want to view and interact with containerd directly, much similar to how you interact with docker.  For example, next I might want to manipulate (build, export, ...) images in containerd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this command worked:

```
sudo crictl -r unix:///run/k3s/containerd/containerd.sock ps -a
```

So I needed to specify the Runtime Endpoint (option -r).

Answer (score 2):

I think that crictl is the best solution to monitor images and containers on the containerd (K8s).

Crictl details and commands:

```
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/blob/master/docs/crictl.md
```

Install crictl with curl:

```
VERSION="v1.26.0" # check latest version in /releases page
curl -L https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/releases/download/$VERSION/crictl-${VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz --output crictl-${VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo tar zxvf crictl-$VERSION-linux-amd64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin
rm -f crictl-$VERSION-linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

Configure to run crictl:

```
sudo nano /etc/crictl.yaml

# copy followings: 
runtime-endpoint: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
image-endpoint: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
timeout: 10
debug: true
```

Sample commands:
List pods:

```
sudo crictl pods
```

List images:

```
sudo crictl images
```

List all pods, containers, images, find the containerid:

```
sudo crictl ps -a
```

Logs for specific container:

```
sudo crictl logs <ContainerID>
```

Run shell on the running container:

```
sudo crictl exec -it <ContainerID> /bin/sh
```

Stop Pod:

```
sudo crictl stopp <PodID>
```

Remove Pod:

```
sudo crictl rmp <PodID>
```

Remove Image:

```
sudo crictl rmi <ImageID>
```

Pulls image from dockerhub:docker.io:

```
sudo crictl pull alpine
```

Inspection of pods:

```
sudo crictl inspectp <PodID, e.g:4e2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **crictl images list** as shown below

[image]

Comment: I'm getting this error:  ```user@k8s-worker3:~$ crictl images list
FATA[0010] failed to connect: failed to connect: context deadline exceeded```